# How to manipulate $a^2b + a^2c + ab^2 + b^2c + ac^2 + bc^2$ into a form for substituting polynomial relations of roots

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial is $2x^3 - x^2 + 14x - 30 = 0$. Through relations of roots (eg.$a + b + c = \frac{-b}{a}$ etc.), I coudl substitute in these values to evalute the value of this express. However, I'm gaving troubel manipulating it into a nice form. I tried taking out $a^2, b^2, c^2$, and $a,b,c$ - even $abc$ (then $a^{-1}, b^{-1}, c^{-1}$ accordingly. None of these ways work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using  $$a+b+c=-1/2$$ we have to find  $$a^2(b+c)+b^2(c+a)+c^2(a+b)=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}-(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$
Can you end it now?

> Hint:use vietas formula along with  $$\displaystyle a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)({(a+b+c)}^2-3ab-3bc-3ca)+3abc$$,

Answer (score 0):

Identically we have
$$
r^2s+s^2r+s^2t+t^2s+t^2r+r^2t
=
(r+s+t)(rs+st+tr)-3rst
$$
and if $r,s,t$ are the roots of the polyomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, then by Vieta's formulas we have
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
&r+s+t=-\frac{b}{a}\\[4pt]
&rs+st+tr=\frac{c}{a}\\[4pt]
&rst=-\frac{d}{a}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
so you have all the ingredients to finish.